# Solving Linear Congruences With Euler Totient Function

Tags: number-theory

I've been asked to solve the following congruence $x^{1667}\equiv2$ $mod$ $2500$. Am I right in saying there's no solution modulo 2500 to this congruence since even though 1667 is coprime to $\varphi(50)=20$, where $\varphi$ is the Euler totient function, the numbers 2 and 2500 aren't coprime and thus this method of solving linear congruences doesn't give rise to any solutions? If I'm wrong, can you tell me where I've gone wrong?

On a similar note, how would one calculate $11^{135246875003}$ modulo 2500 and simialr problems?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x^{1667}\equiv 2 \mod 2500$ implies $x$ is even, so we can write $x=2y$, so that $ 2^{1667}y^{1667}\equiv 2 \mod 2500\iff 2^{1666}y^{1667}\equiv 1 \mod 1250$. This would imply $2$ is a unit modulo $1250$, which is false since $2\cdot 625\equiv 0\mod 1250$. Hence the equation has no solution.

As for the other problem, $11$ and $2500$  are coprime, hence, by Euler's theorem,
$$11^{\varphi(2500)}=11^{1000}\equiv 1 \mod 2500$$ so that $$11^{135246875003}\equiv 11^3=1331\mod 2500.$$

Comment: Am I right in saying Euler's theorem wouldn't work with a number, say 15^12345 modulo 2500? Because 15 isn't coprime to 2500? Would there be a quicker way of calculating that?

Comment: You're right, it wouldn't work. For such a computation, you can decompose $2500$ into coprime factors ($4\times 5^4$) and  use the Chinese Remainder Theorem. Note that for a number that is coprime to $2500$, Bézout's identity allows for easily solving the equation or decide there is no solution.